# Printing long hexadecimal strings

Tags: c, printf

I've written this C function to send an array of 32 bytes to debug output as a string. There's clear repetition in the code. How can I make it neater? The exact format isn't important.

```
// data is guaranteed to be 32 long
void debug_log_32B( uint8_t *data ) {
    char debug_msg[100];
    char fmt[] = "%02X%02X %02X%02X %02X%02X %02X%02X %02X%02X %02X%02X %02X%02X %02X%02X %02X%02X %02X%02X %02X%02X %02X%02X %02X%02X %02X%02X %02X%02X %02X%02X";
    sprintf( debug_msg, fmt,
        data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3], data[4], data[5], data[6], data[7], data[8], data[9],
        data[10], data[11], data[12], data[13], data[14], data[15], data[16], data[17], data[18], data[19],
        data[20], data[21], data[22], data[23], data[24], data[25], data[26], data[27], data[28], data[29],
        data[30], data[31]
    );
    debug_log( debug_msg );
}
```

Even if I created the format string in a loop, the `sprintf` statement would still be long. Or is the code clear enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enter the concept of loops:

```
char buf[0x100];

for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    sprintf(buf + i * 5, "%02X%02X ", data[2 * i], data[2 * i + 1]);
}

debug_log(buf);
```

Comment: +1 Nice and to the point.  Might benefit as to why 0x100 vs OP's 100 vs. 5*16+1 - but that's a nit.

Comment: @chux Thanks. That's my generic "one size fits all" buffer size. But yes, 81 would have been enough.

Answer (score 0):

There comes a point when it makes more sense to handle these things explicitly; otherwise, a more robust solution would rely on [snprintf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf).

```
void debug_log_32B (uint8_t *data)
{
    char debug_msg[0x100];
    char *ptr = debug_msg;

    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    {
        static const char *digits = "0123456789ABCDEF";
        uint8_t u0 = data[i * 2], u1 = data[i * 2 + 1];

        *ptr++ = '0'; *ptr++ = 'X';
        *ptr++ = digits[(u0 >> 4) & 0xf]; *ptr++ = digits[u0 & 0xf];
        *ptr++ = '0'; *ptr++ = 'X';
        *ptr++ = digits[(u1 >> 4) & 0xf]; *ptr++ = digits[u1 & 0xf];

        if (i < 15) *ptr++ = ' ';
    }

    *ptr++ = (0);
    debug_log(debug_msg);
}
```

Faster than using the formatted [s]print[f] overhead, and not dependent on locales. You also have a strict bound on the stack buffer requirements: 16x9 = 144 bytes (0x90).